# I am facing ValueError: Shapes (1, 14) and (1, 139, 14) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

```
import keras
from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention

inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
embd = keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size,
                              300, weights=[embedding_matrix],
                              trainable=False, mask_zero=True, name='Encoder-Word-Embedding')(inputs)
lstm = keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(units=150,
                                                    return_sequences=True))(embd)

att = SeqSelfAttention(attention_type=SeqSelfAttention.ATTENTION_TYPE_MUL,
                       kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-4),
                       bias_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(1e-4),
                       attention_regularizer_weight=1e-4,
                       name='Attention')(lstm)

dense = keras.layers.Dense(units=max_seq_len_y, name='Dense')(att)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[dense])
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss={'Dense': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'},
    metrics={'Dense': 'categorical_accuracy'},
)
model.summary()

history = model.fit(x=X, y=y, batch_size=1, epochs=32)
```

```
X.shape, y.shape
```

> => ((52, 139), (52, 14))

```
 X[0]
```

> array([293,  40, 294, 129,  75, 130, 129, 131, 295, 296, 132,
> 297, 298,
> 2, 299,  34,  12,  76, 300,  27, 301,  15,   1, 302, 133,   4,
> 77, 303,   3, 134, 304,  78,  34, 305,  11, 306, 307,   4,   1,
> 132, 135,  22,  10, 308,  11, 136,   4,   1, 309,  50,   4, 310,
> 11,  78, 311, 312,   3,  77,   1, 313, 130,  10, 137,  11,  12,
> 109,   7, 314, 315,   7,   1,  76, 316,   4, 317, 318,  34, 138,
> 319, 139, 320,   3,  77, 321,  79, 322,   4,   1, 323, 324,   4,
> 1, 325,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
> 0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
> 0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
> 0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0])

```
y[0]
```

> array([1040, 1041,    2, 1042,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
> 0,    0,
> 0,    0,    0])

Here X,y represent the sequences converted using keras tokenizer library. My aim is to learn title of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add activation='softmax' in your last Dense layer.